# Installing packages from packages.list in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

I have file called packages.list which has the name of the packages like:

```
a11y-profile-manager        install
a11y-profile-manager-indicator  install
account-plugin-facebook     install
account-plugin-flickr       install
account-plugin-google       install
accountsservice             install
acl                         install
acpi-support                install
acpid                       install
activity-log-manager        install
adduser                     install
adium-theme-ubuntu          install
adwaita-icon-theme          install
adwaita-icon-theme-full     install
aisleriot                   install
alsa-base                   install
alsa-utils                  install
anacron                     install
apg                         install
..
.
```

I want to know is there any way to install the packages listed in the file using apt and also I want to ignore any packages that are already installed.

Comment: That looks like it is in the format provided by the `dpkg --get-selections` command - and so *should* be readable by `dpkg --set-selections`. However there are some caveats about package availability - see the `dpkg` manual page

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this command is useful for your requirement.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

As directed by @steeldriver the packages.list file is provided by the `dpkg --get-selections` and hence they are readable by `dpkg --set-selections` . So the solution:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Packages.list
```